# Java Constructors GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, constructor

so i have a question from my book that i have to do, but dont understand it completely, if someone helps in anyway that would be awesome.

**Question:**
Java API has the GregorianCalendar class in the java.util package. which you can use to obtain the year, month, and day of a date. The no-arg constructor custructs an instance for the current date, and the methods: get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR). (GregorianCalendar.Month). and get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) return the year, month, and day. Write a program to perform two tasks.

1. Display the current year, month and day.
2. the GregorianCalendar class has the setTimeInMillis(long). which can be used to set a specified elapsed time since january 1, 1970. Set the value to 12345678765L and display the year, month, and day.

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html. You can use a DateFormatter to display your date nicely, or use the get method inherited from the Calendar class, providing the right field you want to have.

Comment: ahhh okay cool that helps alot!

Comment: You do realize you have `GregorianCalender` all over the place, when the correct name is `GregorianCalendar` (calendAr), right?

Comment: well.. its a question in my book, just rewrote it :b

Comment: oh... -.- thats what you meant.. sorry xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming GMT TimeZone

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date now = new Date();
calendar.setTime(now);

//today
day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);


calendar.setTimeInMillis(12345678765L);


day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

The book wants you to use the GregorianCalendar class, which you import from java.util package or let Eclipse import it automatically.  That class has methods to get the year, month, and day.

It just wants you to write a program to show the current date using that class.  After that, it wants you to use its setTimeInMillis method and show that result.

Basically something like this:

```
System.out.println("DAY_OF_MONTH: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("YEAR: " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("MONTH: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));

getTimeInMillis(12345678765L);
```

Hope that clears it up for you.

Answer (score -1):

@ZouZou This is what i got, works perfectly. thank you

```
  public static void main(String args[])
       {
          int day, month, year;
          int second, minute, hour;
          GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

          day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
          month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

          second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
          minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
          hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);

          System.out.println("Current date is  "+(month + 1)+"/"+day+"/"+year);
          System.out.println("Current time is  "+hour+" : "+minute+" : "+second);
       }
    }
```